# What am I doing wrong in this Pascal's triangle generator?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, nested

I am trying to print Pascal's triangle using Python. I am using nested lists and loops. It works something like this. For n = 2 it should print:

```
  1
 1 1
1 2 1
```

This is my code:

```
n = int(input("Enter the limit: "))
triangle = []
currentRow = 0
for currentRow in range(n+1):
    spaces = n - currentRow
    printables = currentRow - 1
    temp = []
    while spaces > 0:
        temp.append(" ")
        spaces -= 1
    while printables > 0:
        if currentRow == 0:
            temp.append("1")
            triangle.append(temp)
            temp.clear()
        else:
            try:
                if (triangle[currentRow - 1][(spaces + 1) - 1]) == " " or (triangle[currentRow - 1][(spaces + 1) + 1]) == " ":
                    temp.append("1 ")
                else:
                    temp.append(f"{int(triangle[currentRow - 1][(spaces - 1) + 1]) + int(triangle[currentRow - 1][(spaces + 1) + 1])} ")
                triangle.append(temp)
                temp.clear()
            except IndexError:
                pass
print(triangle)
```

I have no idea why but it keeps printing nothing for the triangle list even though I am appending my values to it continuously. Someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You set `printables` only once, but the condition for your `while` loop checks for `printables > 0`. If you don't change the value of `printables`, the loop will never terminate.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe that I am so dumb. But there is a new problem which I just edited into the post. Can you help me with that, please?

Comment: Don't edit your question after it has been answered, and don't ask separate questions for every single stumbling point you encounter. Take more than 30 seconds to try to solve your next problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a 3-step approach to this problem.

First of all, create a function that generates the rows of a Pascal triangle in numeric form.

Secondly, build a list of strings that represent each row in the triangle.

Lastly, print the rows centred on the width of the last (longest) string.

P is the number of rows required in the triangle

```
def pascal(n: int) -> list[list[int]]:
    r = [[1]]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        p = r[-1]
        r.append([1] + [sum(p[j-1:j+1]) for j in range(1, i-1)] + [1])
    return r

P = 10 # number of rows in the triangle

out = [' '.join(map(str, e)) for e in pascal(P)]

w = len(out[-1]) # width of longest item

print(*(e.center(w) for e in out), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
             1             
            1 1            
           1 2 1           
          1 3 3 1          
         1 4 6 4 1         
       1 5 10 10 5 1       
      1 6 15 20 15 6 1     
    1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1    
   1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1  
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Comment: I did not get the part where you added the width. Even though it is all complex but can you pls explain the width part?

Comment: @ZeyRoax Python string objects (type *str*) have a built-in function called *center()* You can read about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str

Comment: I know that but the way you calculated out using the map thing is not understandable. Did you just combine all the lists and then did -1 for the last line? Is it like that?

Comment: @ZeyRoax An index value of -1 refers to the last item in a non-zero length list. The triangle is constructed such that the last row is the longest. Therefore it's easy to figure out the maximum required width then centre all the shorter rows around that

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a slightly more compact solution.

```
P= []
for k in range(10):
    for i in range(len(P)-1, 0, -1):
        P[i]+= P[i-1]
    P.append(1)
    print(P)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
```

---

Or with an implicit loop,

```
P=[]
for k in range(10):
    P= [1] + [P[i] + (P[i+1] if i+1 < len(P) else 0) for i in range(len(P))]
    print(P)
```

Comment: May you please explain to me the len(p)-1, 0, -1 part? For everything else. I got it.

Comment: @ZeyRoax: it is simply a backward loop, to avoid modifying values that are still needed.

Comment: then why is there not an error for the first approach the length will be 0 and 0-1 = -1 and we can not reach 0 by going backward from -1.

Comment: @ZeyRoax: the loop is not executed, That's the intended behavior.

Comment: oh thanks. this approach is so damn easy. Thank you so much. I have been working on my long approach for 3 days. You are damn crazy! One last thing, can I know from where did you learn all of this advanced stuff. I wanna learn it as well.

Comment: @ZeyRoax: it's easy, just daily programming practice for 47 years.

Comment: 47 years! you kidding right? even python isn't out for that long

Comment: I started with FORTRAN IV. Then Pascal, Basic, Z80 Assembly, FORTRAN 77, APL, DCL, M68000 Assembly, PDP-11 Assembly, GWBasic, Turbo Pascal & Delphi, C, Unix shells, C++, Java, Visual Basic, Python, C#... Oh, I forget SR-56, TI-58 & 59 in the early days. :) Would have loved to work with ADA and Oberon.

Comment: May I get to know what magic have you done in your code that if I try to copy paste your code it works but if I write my own code then it gives IndexOutOfRange Error here **P[i]+= P[i-1]**

Comment: @ZeyRoax: you tried an index out of range, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You code is overly complex because you are trying to combine computations with formatting.  Also, while loops are a lot more error prone than for loops, which you should be using here because all iterations are predictable.

So you should change your approach to separate computations (building a list of numbers) and formatting (indent, spacing and printing).

If you want the output to be nicely balanced, you can print numbers with a fixed width (based on the largest value) and center each line based on the maximum total width.

In order to know the printing width of values, you can generate all the pascal triangle lines beforehand and measure the size of the largest number as a string.

```
# pascal triangle lines
N = 10
P = [[1]]  
P.extend( [1,*map(sum,zip(P[-1],P[-1][1:])),1] for _ in range(1,N) )

# determine fixed value printing width 
width  = len(str(max(P[-1]))) + 2 # extra for spacing (* 2 for no overlap)

# print each line centred, with centred numbers
for line in P:
    print("".join(str(n).center(width) for n in line).center(width*N))
```

output for N = 10:

```
                             1                              
                          1     1                           
                       1     2     1                        
                    1     3     3     1                     
                 1     4     6     4     1                  
              1     5     10    10    5     1               
           1     6     15    20    15    6     1            
        1     7     21    35    35    21    7     1         
     1     8     28    56    70    56    28    8     1      
  1     9     36    84   126   126    84    36    9     1
```

output for N = 9:

```
                 1                  
               1   1                
             1   2   1              
           1   3   3   1            
         1   4   6   4   1          
       1   5   10  10  5   1        
     1   6   15  20  15  6   1      
   1   7   21  35  35  21  7   1    
 1   8   28  56  70  56  28  8   1
```

You could also compute the pascal lines as you go but you need to estimate the size of the largest value in order to get proper formatting.  For a Pascal triangle the sum of numbers on each line is 2^N so the maximum value of a line will be at most half of that.

```
# pascal triangle size
N = 10

# estimate fixed value printing width
width  = len(str(2**(N-1))) + 2 # extra for spacing

# print each line centred, with centred numbers
P = [1]
for i in range(N):
    print("".join(str(n).center(width) for n in P).center(width*N))
    P = [1,*map(sum,zip(P,P[1:])),1] # compute next line


                             1                              
                          1     1                           
                       1     2     1                        
                    1     3     3     1                     
                 1     4     6     4     1                  
              1     5     10    10    5     1               
           1     6     15    20    15    6     1            
        1     7     21    35    35    21    7     1         
     1     8     28    56    70    56    28    8     1      
  1     9     36    84   126   126    84    36    9     1
```

To make this cleaner, you should completely isolate the pascal line calculation in a function that you then use in the formatting/printing code:

Calculations:

```
def pascalLine(N):
    r = [1]
    for p in range(N): 
        r.append(r[-1]*(N-p)//(p+1))
    return r
```

Formatting and printing:

```
N     = 10
width = len(str(max(pascalLine(N-1))))*2
for i in range(N):
    line = "".join(f"{n:^{width}}" for n in pascalLine(i)).center(width*N)
    print(line)

                             1                              
                          1     1                           
                       1     2     1                        
                    1     3     3     1                     
                 1     4     6     4     1                  
              1     5     10    10    5     1               
           1     6     15    20    15    6     1            
        1     7     21    35    35    21    7     1         
     1     8     28    56    70    56    28    8     1      
  1     9     36    84   126   126    84    36    9     1
```